# Why are there two ways to retrieve values from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python there are basically two ways to get a value from a dictionary:

1. `dictionary["key"]`
2. `dictionary.get("key")`

Is there any - maybe historical - reason for this behavior?

I sometimes stumble upon this while switching from JavaScript frontend development to Python backend development forgetting that `dictionary["key"]` results in a `KeyError` when the key is not present instead of returning `None`, which is the behaviour of the `get` method.

What is the background/design decision for those two ways? Is it for performance reasons - knowing a value is present reading it is more performant?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Does the post you linked explain "why" this is used? I asked for the language design decision. So at some point in time somone has thought "it might be a good idea to have two ways". I am not interested in explaining the workings of both but want to know why that concept was chosen.

Comment: It does touch on the performance aspects you asked about. Beyond that this is arguably [Zen](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/): _"Errors should never pass silently."_ (something missing you expected to be there should fail loudly); _"Unless explicitly silenced."_ (use `.get` if that's acceptable). Python also has more of a convention around liberally throwing and catching errors than other languages - [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP).

Comment: Also for interest note that you can implement [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) on a mapping to intercept `KeyError`s, or [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for index access in general.

Comment: Flipping the question round: why is there not a concise way to do "get or throw if not present" in JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not safe to use"? You can `catch KeyError`

Comment: "safe to use" is distracting from the question so I removed that part.

Comment: It's even more exciting if you switch between Ruby and Python. In Python, `[]` is "get or throw" and `.get` is "get or default value". In Ruby, `[]` is "get or default value" and `.fetch` is "get or throw". Try keeping *that* straight in your head.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Though I was not involved into the design of Python, I think I can make an educated guess:

```
 dictionary["key"]
```

is shorter and very convenient to use, since it is consistent with access to other containers like lists, tuples, or strings.

`dictionary.get`, however, has a different behaviour when the key is not contained in the dictionary, since it simply returns `None` and does not throw an exception. There are many use cases where this behaviour can be more handy and allows more concise code than adding a try/catch around a bracket statement. Note also there is a  `dictionary.get` variant with 2 parameters which allows to specify an alternative to `None`.

So in short, both variants can be useful, and they are not interchangeable, since they have a different failure mode. Use square brackets when you prefer to get an exception in case of a missing key, and `get` when you prefer to get no exception (and a return value of `None` instead).

Comment: Note that `dictionary[key]` is just syntactic sugar for `dictionary.__getitem__(key)` so you can effectively use the brackets syntax as a higher order function as well. See also the `operator` module.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: see my edit.

Comment: Whether you use `get` or `__getitem__` depends on whether you want the throwing behaviour, not on which is more convenient.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: you are right, I was under impression get with one parameter has the same throwing behaviour as [], missed that. Give me a minute to edit my answer.

Comment: +1 but I would add that get() allows for specifying a default value other than None.  I would typically use `[]` when a missing key can only the result of a bug.  In that situtation `KeyError` with the key that was missing is a more informative exception than something like 'cannot compare int to None' or whatever happens later with the `None` value.

Comment: @JimmyJames. *"but I would add that get() allows for specifying a default value other than None."* - that's exactly what I already wrote.

Comment: @DocBrown Sorry, I missed it.  My bad.

Comment: Besides having .get() return a value other than None with the second parameter, you can also use `dict.setdefault(key, value)` to set a default value that will always be returned for that key if it doesn't exist, even overriding the 2nd parameter of `.get()`.  There is also `collections.defaultdict(callable)` which will always return the result of the callable if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: @RisingZan: your explanation of `setdefault` sounds confusing to me. Here is my explanation: `setdefault` does not set a default value, it is simply a conditional `set` operation for dictionaries:  when `key` exists in the dictionary, the related item is unchanged. If it not exists, `dict.setdefault(key, value)` is equivalent to `dict[key]=value`. In both cases, the return value of `setdefault `is the final value which is associated to the key `key`.

Comment: @DocBrown  You are correct. I  don't use `setdefault` often and mixed up how it works, forgetting that it does actually set the value if not defined, then returns the value (as opposed to defaultdict, which calls the callable when you try to get the value)  Personally I think `setdefault` somewhat misnamed, and it really should be something like `set_if_undefined`, even if that is too wordy.